# Migration from TFS to Azure DevOps Services from a certain Changeset

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration, changeset

I need to migrate a Project (TFVC) from TFS 2012 to Azure DevOps Service (Git). I would also like to migrate the project history. The problem I have, is that the 10 newest changesets are rubbish. So I would like to migrate from an older changeset with all the changeset history before this changeset. Is this possible? Has anyone got any experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to migrate from an older changeset with all the changeset history before this changeset. Is this possible?

I am afraid there is such way we could migrate from TFS to Azure DevOps Services with a certain Changesets.

As we know, the changesets/bugs/test cases/history are included when migrate TFS to Azure DevOps Services. But all the data operates at a **database level** rather than data, all the data are stored in the database. So, we could not exclude the date of 10 newest changesets in the database when you migrate from TFS to Azure DevOps Services.

Hope this helps.